# Amazing SQL Error 1024 when create database in Mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

when execute `create database if not exists 7e7 ;`

get error:

> " SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn:67) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '7e7' at line 1
>   Query is : create database if not exists 7e7 "

but execute `create database if not exists 7b7 ;`, its ok.

**why?**

> docker container, mariadb:10.2
>
> version   10.2.19-MariaDB-1:10.2.19+maria~bionic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7e7 looks too much like the number 70,000,000, in scientific notation.

When in doubt, surround database, table, and column names with backtics:

```
`7e7`
```